# Testing link properties (a tag) with ReactJS and Jasmine

Tags: jasmine, reactjs

I have a component created with react which has a link that acts a button. I need to find out if the button text (the link text) is the expected one. I'm able to find the link using:

```
var EditButton = TestUtils.scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithClass(slugBox, 'button tiny')
```

But I'm not able to locate the property of the `EditButton` which stores the text. Expected to be edit.

Any documentation about testing this kind of things will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EditButton[0].getDomNode().textContent